# JQuery UI Autocomplete not displaying result automatically at the first time

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using JQuery UI Autocomplete feature for displaying the results. It seems to be working correctly in every case accept the one I am pasting the value in the textbox for the very first time. It fetches the result but the autocomplete does not show the results unless and until **I have to press the down key**. One i press the key, it shows the autocomplete ui with the results. The next time I paste the word to search, it works perfectly fine and shows the autocomplete result. Below is the code I am using:

```
$("input.autocompleteData").on('input', function (e) {
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        var txtVal = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        var pastedValue = true;
        getAutoCompletedata($(this), txtVal, pastedValue);
    });

function getAutoCompletedata(cntl, input, pastedValue) {

        var self = this;
        if (input.length < 2) {
            // Clear the array
            self.hqListData = [];
        }
        else if (input.length == 2 || pastedValue) {

            getHQListData(input);
        }
        // first clear array
        self.hqFilterListData = [];
        // fill data 
        // for text length greater than minLengthForSearch filter data from array
        $.each(self.hqListData, function (i, val) {

            if (val != undefined && val != null && val.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(input) >= 0) {

                //push data into payerFilterList
                self.hqFilterListData.push({ label: val.name, value: val.id });
            }
        });




        $(cntl).autocomplete({
            source: self.hqFilterListData, scroll: true, select: function (e, ui) {
                var uniqueId = new Date().getTime();
                var alreadyAdded = false;

                $("div#resultsection input[type='hidden']").each(function (i) {
                    if (unescape(this.value).trim() === unescape(ui.item.value).trim()) {
                        alreadyAdded = true;
                        return false;
                    }
                });
                if (!alreadyAdded) {
                    $("#resultsection").empty();
                    $("#resultsection").append("<span id='" + uniqueId + "' class='multiselectContainer'><span class='indivSelectedText'>" + ui.item.label + "</span><input class='indivSelectedValue'  type='hidden' value=" + escape(ui.item.value) + " ></input> <a href='#' class='fa fa-times-circle labelclose'></a></span>");
                }
                $(cntl).val('');
                return false;
            },
            focus: function (event, ui) {
                $(this).val(ui.item.label);
                return false;
            }
        });



    }

function getHQListData(input) {
        var self = this;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "ReviewPools.aspx/GetHQList",
            data: JSON.stringify({ 'searchText': input }),
            dataType: "json",
            async: false,
            success: function (output) {
                var retVal = JSON.parse(output.d); // output.d
                if (retVal.length === 0) {
                    alert("No Headquarter Found");
                    return false;
                }
                self.hqListData = [];
                $.each(retVal, function (i, val) {
                    self.hqListData.push({ "id": val.BUSINESS_RID, "name": val.COMPANY_NAME });
                });
            },
            error: function (errormsg) {
                alert(errormsg.responseText);
                state = 0;
            }
        });
    }
```

Everything is working fine accept the first time I paste the value. It does get the result but it is displayed only when pressing the down key. Is it a problem with the JqueryUI? What am I missing?

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
<input type="text" onpaste="myFunction()" value="Paste something in here">
```